# Problema com acentuação ao salvar texto no banco de dados

Tags: primefaces, postgresql, utf-8, acentuação, utf8-decode

Bom dia galera, estou com o seguinte problema. Meu sistema faz alterações em uma tabela na base de dados, se o conteúdo for inserido diretamente por script no postgres, a acentuação funciona normalmente, mas ao atualizar o texto pelo sistema, a acentuação não funciona. Segue código do xhtml e do manageBean:

---

XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> <h:body>     <ui:composition template="/pages/protected/templates/master.xhtml">         <ui:define name="divMain">      <h:form>        <h2 style="padding-left:10px;">Customização da Certidão de Dívida Ativa</h2>        <table>             <tr>
                <td>
                    <h:outputText value="Título do Relatório: " style="margin-left:5px;"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p:inputTextarea rows="1"
                                label="dsTitulo" style="width:1000px;"
                                counterTemplate="{0} caracteres restantes."
                                id="dsTitulo"
                                value="#{div_customizacao_certidao_divida_ativaMB.dsTitulo}"
                                required="true" />
                </td>           </tr>           <tr>
                <td>
                    <p:commandButton action="#{div_customizacao_certidao_divida_ativaMB.update()}"  
                              value="Salvar" ajax="false">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </td>           </tr>   
                    </table>            </h:form>                   </ui:define>    </ui:composition> </h:body> </html>
```

---

MB

```
public void update() {
    try {
        certidaoDividaAtivaCustomizacao.setDescricaoTitulo(getDsTitulo());
        getCertidaoDividaAtivaCustomizacaoFacade().update(certidaoDividaAtivaCustomizacao);
        displayInfoMessageToUser("Registro salvo com sucesso!");
        certidaoDividaAtivaCustomizacao = null;
        loadCertidaoDividaAtivaCustomizacao();
    } catch (RollbackException ce) {
        ce.printStackTrace();
        try {
            Exception ex = ce;
            while (!(ex instanceof BatchUpdateException)) {
                ex = (Exception) ex.getCause();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            displayErrorMessageToUser(ce.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        displayErrorMessageToUser(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Como mostrado na figura abaixo, está utilizando codificação UTF-8.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema. Coloquei acceptcharset="ISO-8859-1" dentro do         `<h:form>`, ficou assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Não necessariamente o problema é o banco. Eu até apostaria que não é.

Me parece que o XHTML não define explicitamente qual a codificação; é bom rever isso.

Muita coisa pode interferir na codificação do texto entre o que o usuário digita e o que o SGBD grava no disco. Por exemplo:

- a codificação em que o arquivo foi salvo ou compilado (o servidor pode usar isso para deduzir que codificação usar)
- alguma configuração do servidor - ele pode estar forçando uma codificação específica nos cabeçalhos HTML, por exemplo (https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding)
- o proxy reverso, se estiver utilizando um (veja opções como charset no NGinx e AddDefaultCharset no Apache)
- o SO em que o servidor está rodando
- a configuração da conexão ao banco de dados
- a configuração do próprio Postgres (veja https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html)
- a configuração do usuário do SO que iniciou o serviço (sério: já vi erros do tipo "só funciona direito quando fulano reinicia")

etc.

O problema costuma ser: alguém no meio da fila por onde a informação passa (nos casos em que vi: browser-proxy-aplicação-pool-bd) recebe um texto, por exemplo, em ISO, supõe erroneamente que o próximo da fila está esperando um UTF-8, e gentilmente faz a conversão, bagunçando tudo.

Eu sugiro, se possível, manter sempre a mesma codificação em tudo. Não é obrigatório: você pode ter um formulário mandando em UTF-8 para um servidor que recebe em ISO (conversão) que por sua vez grava em UTF-8 (conversão) numa conexão a um BD que foi criado como ISO (conversão).

Pelo bem da sua sanidade mental, não faça isso; mas se fizer, explicite a codificação em cada ponto. Mexer só no Postgres pode resolver, mas também pode não resultar em nada - ele pode definir a codificação padrão dos clientes, mas se o Pool de conexões estiver configurado para usar outra, ele vai pedir para trocar e o banco vai obedecer.

Comment: Vlw pela resposta Uriel, bem completa. Tive Debbugando o código e o problema é no valor que vem da tela, pois assim que eu clico em salvar, vai para o método UPDATE, e o item já puxa o valor da tela convetido. Só que ainda não consegui resolver o problema. Já tentei muder de <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?> para <?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>   mas também não funcionou.
O banco está configurado certo. 
Tenho outras telas no sistema que atualizam ou inserem valores no banco e não tem problema com acentuação, mas por algum motivo está tela não salva corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize client-encoding e server-encoding compatíveis.

Consulte o manual:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-FORMAT

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda.